# extracting predictors from ctree object

Tags: r, decision-tree, party

I've checked `binary tree` class methods, and [How to extract tree structure from ctree function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675664/how-to-extract-tree-structure-from-ctree-function) (which was helpful understanding S4 object structure and slots), but it's still unclear how to get to the final predictors of a `ctree` object. For `rpart`, I'd use something like

```
 extract_preds <- function( tt ){
   leaves <- tt$frame$var == '<leaf>'
   as.character( unique( tt$frame$var[ leaves==F ] ) )
 }
```

Is there a similar shortcut available, or do I have to write a recursive function to traverse the `ctree` object and extract the predictors? That, or a regex-fest with the print output? Thanks.

UPDATE: using **baydoganm**'s code below. Still have to figure out how to update `res` properly through the recursions:

```
 library(party)

 ctree_preds <- function(tr,vnames){    
    res <- character(0)
    traverse <- function(treenode,vnames,res){
    if(treenode$terminal){
        return(res)
    } else {
        res <- c(res,vnames[treenode$psplit$variableID])
        traverse(treenode$left , vnames, res )
        traverse(treenode$right, vnames, res )
        }
    }
    traverse(tr,vnames,res)
    return(unique(res))
 }

 airq <- subset(airquality, !is.na(Ozone))
 airct <- ctree(Ozone ~ ., data = airq,
                         controls = ctree_control(maxsurrogate = 3))
 plot(airct)

 ctree_preds(airct@tree,names(airq)[-1])
```

Comment: You have to traverse the tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is the script I implemented to traverse the tree from a `ctree` object. I use the same example in the `party` package which is `airct` dataset.

```
require(party)
data(airquality)

traverse <- function(treenode){
    if(treenode$terminal){
        bas=paste("Current node is terminal node with",treenode$nodeID,'prediction',treenode$prediction)
        print(bas)
        return(0)
    } else {
        bas=paste("Current node",treenode$nodeID,"Split var. ID:",treenode$psplit$variableName,"split value:",treenode$psplit$splitpoint,'prediction',treenode$prediction)
        print(bas)
}
traverse(treenode$left)
traverse(treenode$right)
}

airq <- subset(airquality, !is.na(Ozone))
airct <- ctree(Ozone ~ ., data = airq,
controls = ctree_control(maxsurrogate = 3))
plot(airct)

traverse(airct@tree)
```

This function, `traverse`, just traverses the tree in a depth-first order. You can change the order of the traversal by changing the recursive part.

Moreover, if you want to return other node characteristics, I would recommend checking the structure of the ctree object.

edit: Minor code revisions.

Comment: I've run the code above and the node `varriableID` doesn't print. Since the objective is to get a vector with predictor names, I'm working with your code to figure this out (see question). What I'm struggling with is how to update `res` through the recursions in a way similar to C's address operator.

Comment: I am not sure if you we use the same party package but the code above works for me. If you are interested in printing the name of the variable, just change `treenode$psplit$variableID` with `treenode$psplit$variableName`. However I am not sure if this is what you are asking. I also updated the code little bit.

Comment: I used the fuction `capture.output` to store the values in a data.frame for further processing

Answer (score 1):

The [mlmeta](https://github.com/az0/mlmeta) R package's ctree2sas() function converts fitted ctree models to SAS code.  It can be easily adapted to other languages and is generally instructive on the internals of the object.

Answer (score 1):

```
split <- 
c(cart@tree$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$right$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$left$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$right$right$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$right$left$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$left$right$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$left$left$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$right$right$right$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$right$right$left$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$right$left$right$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$right$left$left$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$left$right$right$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$left$right$left$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$left$left$right$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$left$left$left$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$right$right$right$right$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$right$right$right$left$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$right$right$left$right$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$right$right$left$left$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$right$left$right$right$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$right$left$right$left$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$right$left$left$right$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$right$left$left$left$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$left$right$right$right$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$left$right$right$left$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$left$right$left$right$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$left$right$left$left$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$left$left$right$right$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$left$left$right$left$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$left$left$left$right$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$left$left$left$left$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$left$left$left$left$left$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$left$left$left$left$right$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$left$left$left$right$left$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$left$left$left$right$right$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$left$left$right$left$left$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$left$left$right$left$right$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$left$left$right$right$left$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$left$left$right$right$right$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$left$right$left$left$left$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$left$right$left$left$right$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$left$right$left$right$left$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$left$right$left$right$right$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$left$right$right$left$left$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$left$right$right$left$right$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$left$right$right$right$left$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$left$right$right$right$right$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$right$left$left$left$left$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$right$left$left$left$right$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$right$left$left$right$left$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$right$left$left$right$right$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$right$left$right$left$left$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$right$left$right$left$right$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$right$left$right$right$left$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$right$left$right$right$right$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$right$right$left$left$left$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$right$right$left$left$right$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$right$right$left$right$left$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$right$right$left$right$right$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$right$right$right$left$left$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$right$right$right$left$right$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$right$right$right$right$left$psplit$splitpoint , cart@tree$right$right$right$right$right$psplit$splitpoint)

split <- split[order(split)]
```