# How to traverse the tree structure of rpart object in R? I need to get all the nodes associated with a subtree, how can I do it?

Tags: r, classification, rpart

I am using rpart for building a decision tree classifier. I wish to use my own pruning function based on certain parameters of the leaf nodes corresponding to a subtree. For this, I think I need to traverse the tree. I explored the documentation of rpart, but could not come up with a way to do it. Please help.

Comment: The function `dendrapply()` might be what you're looking for

Comment: You could use the `as.party()` coercion function from the `partykit` package. This transforms the `rpart` structure to a structure called `party` that comes with many convenience tools including a `nodeapply()` and a `nodeprune()` function. See `vignette("partykit", package = "partykit")` for an introduction and `vignette("constparty", package = "partykit")` for examples including coercion from `rpart`.

Comment: @Andrie `dendrapply()` function applies a passed function to each node and returns the altered tree. This is not what I'm looking for. I wish to get every leaf node corresponding to a subtree.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the tree traversal code I had at [extracting predictors from ctree object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713275/extracting-predictors-from-ctree-object)

Potentially, this will be useful.